# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'photoshop' referenced before assignment

Tags: conv-neural-network, python-3.6

I am working on Dog Breed classifier, I am getting the following the error when I run the train code for my model.

I tried to downgrade the pillow version, but still facing the same issue.

Error shown in the line model_scratch:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-360fef19693f> in <module>
      1 #training the model
      2 model_scratch = train(5, loaders_scratch, model_scratch, optimizer_scratch, 
----> 3                       criterion_scratch)

<ipython-input-11-c90fddb93f0d> in train(n_epochs, loaders, model, optimizer, criterion)
      9         #train model
     10         model.train()
---> 11         for batch_idx, (data,target) in enumerate(loaders['train']):
     12 
     13             # zero the parameter (weight) gradients


UnboundLocalError: local variable 'photoshop' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Does the word "photoshop" appear anywhere in your ipynb? Perhaps you pasted something accidentally?

Comment: No, photoshop doesn't appear in my ipynb

Comment: That's... quite an impossible error. Can you by any chance share the ipynb you are trying to run? Of course it would be best if you could reduce it to a mininum failing example, but I guess I can show you how to do that.

Comment: You can find the ipynb file at this GitHub link: https://github.com/gprashmi/Dog_breed_classifier/blob/master/dog_breed_classifier.ipynb

Comment: Ah... so it's a PIL issue. Why didn't you include the conplete stack trace in the question though... And which PIL version did you downgrade to?

Comment: Sorry about that...I downgraded to 4.2.1

Comment: When I tried to do `pip3 install pillow==4.2.1`, it complained that I don't have zlib. Are you sure you downgraded successfully? Pillow 5.4.1 can be installed without zlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3769) in Pillow 6.0.0. Based on the line number information in your linked full stack trace, I think your downgrade didn't succeed, and you are still using 6.0.0. Either downgrading to 5.4.1, or building from the latest source, should fix this problem, although the latter option is probably a little difficult for the average user.

Comment: Downgraded to pillow 5.4.1...and it worked, thank you!